# How to Take Checkboxes in Python

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, checkbox, webapp2

I am trying to use checkboxes in my HTML, return these checkboxes to my python backend, and then increment three counters if the box is clicked.

Right now my HTML is as follows and works fine:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="checkbox inline" name="adjective" value="entertaining">Entertaining
    <input type="checkbox inline" name="adjective" value="informative">Informative
    <input type="checkbox inline" name="adjective" value="exceptional">Exceptional
</form>
```

and then on my python backend I have the following:

```
def post(self):
    adjective = self.request.get('adjective ')

    if adjective :
        #somehow tell if the entertaining box was checked
        #increment entertaining counter
        #do the same for the others
```

Comment: i think maybe make the name in html "adjective[]" ... maybe ...

Comment: You do know you can just `print adjective` to see what's in there, right? It'll end up mixed in with your HTML but you can just view source to have a look...

Comment: @kindall that would be good for debugging but I need to do it programatically so that it will work each time on the backend

Comment: Yes, but by debugging you can easily see how to do it pro grammatically, by seeing what you're getting, which will determine how to access it.

Comment: Are you using `webapp` or `webapp2`? They have slightly different APIs for getting multiple values from a request.

Comment: @Blckknght I am using webapp2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When your form has multiple checkboxes with the same `name` attribute, the request will have multiple values for that name when the form is submitted.

Your current code uses `Request.get` to get a value, but this will only retrieve the first value if there is more than one. Instead, you can get all the values using `Request.get_all(name)` (in webapp) or `Request.get(name, allow_multiple=True)` (in webapp2). This will return a (possibly empty) list with all the values for that name.

Here's how you could use in in your code:

```
def post(self):
    adjectives = self.request.get('adjective', allow_multiple=True)
    for a in adjectives:
        # increment count
        self.adjective_count[a] += 1 # or whatever

        # do more stuff with adjective a, if you want

    # do other stuff with the request
```

Comment: thanks! makes sense but I couldn't find this all that easily online

Comment: I think [this](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/request.html) is the relevant section of the docs.

Answer (score 0):

wouldnt it be easier to change the name="" and put it the same as the value, so you can jsut ask

IF entertaining :

IF informative :

im no python programmer just tell let you no

Comment: yes I agree this is a good bit easier but I don't think it is really the proper way.  I may be wrong though.

Comment: is there like a switch statement where like if adjective == entertaing:
//print code

or switch 
case 1 if adjective == entertaining:
//execute

case 2 if adjective == informative:
//execute

Comment: Python doesn't have a switch statement. Usually the alternative is to use a dictionary. But I'm afraid I don't actually understand your suggested code (it might help to put it in the answer, where you can format it properly).

Comment: srry i forgot to use the code tags,  but i mean something that checks the value of "adjective", via a equal sign, or something i think the default value should be whichever selected in the form(entertaining, exceptional, or informative) not null or 0 or no value, but again i dont know how python works, but maybe there is similar code that your aware of that i dont know the terms to in python, so if u can compare the value of "adjective" to the sting set "informative" or whichever you choose